# How do I make web service calls within nginx?

Tags: nginx

### What:

I want to make requests to a web service from within nginx on each request that goes through nginx and apply some process based on the response I get from the web service.

### Application:

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy and have multiple webservices to which traffic is routed to. I want to add an additional webservice (Lets call this AdminService) that would act as admin, this service would handle things like security, billing and other traffic analytics and preprocessing. 
For every request the goes through nginx I need to make a request to AdminService, admin service will then analyse the request updating some statistics and the likes and respond with some tags. nginx will then update some headers based on the returned tags and forward the request to the appropriate url.

I've taken a look at the Lua module and it doesn't seem to do webservice call.
I also see that there are Java, Groovy and Clojure modules available, is this perhaps what I should be looking at? Otherwise what should I be looking at?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option is to use the [auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) module. It's not designed with your scenario in mind and is not a default Nginx module so you need to build from source to compile it in with ./configure --with-http_auth_request_module.

auth_request is used to pre-authenticate Nginx requests via an remote HTTP call. As long as the response header is HTTP 200, then the initial request is processed as normal. This could be used to send the request to your AdminService and the response would be able to determine what happened next.

Something like:

```
# Default location
location / {
    auth_request /AdminService;

    # Look for X_UpstreamHost: header in the response
    auth_request_set $x_upstreamhost $upstream_http_x_upstreamhost;

    # Use the value of the response header to choose the internal processing host
    proxy_pass http://$x_upstreamhost;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

}

# Send requests for AdminService to the AdminService
# This expects AdminService to be listening on a path called AdminService
# and based at ##adminip##
location /AdminService {
     proxy_pass http://##adminip##;
}
```

This will send incoming requests first to the host defined by AdminService. This service must response with a normal 200 header and also x_upstreamhost: #internalHost#. Where #internalHost# is the ip or dn of the host you want to handle the request.

Try it out and if you run into issues, post your server {} block and somebody will take a look.

Comment: This looks promising, I will try it out.
I'm assuming this is the documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html

If I would be able to use the other headers in the response from AdminService before the request is sent to x_upstreamhost then this would be exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes, that's the docs and yes it's easy to pass values back to nginx via the headers and auth_request_set.

Comment: It doesn't look like I can access the headers from AdminService's response. I tried both $http_{name} and $upstream_http_{name}, both seem to give me headers from the original request.

Comment: `auth_request_set $myheader $upstream_http_$myheader;` Should work for a header called Myheader: If the header wasn't set in the original request, it's hard to see how it could be used from there.

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish that using nginx_lua (I like the [openresty](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) version) by having a script on the [access-by-lua](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/#access-by-lua-file) phase to handle your custom processing.

In that script, you could use [ngx-location-capture](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/#ngx-location-capture) to call your "AdminService" if that webservice is defined as a nginx location; or you could using a http client library (I've used [this one](https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http)) to call external services.

See a similar use case [here.](http://www.stavros.io/posts/writing-an-nginx-authentication-module-in-lua/)

Comment: I haven't looked at the links you have provided extensively and would like to avoid getting in too deep right now.
I need to be able to access the headers from the response I get from "AdminService" and update the request that will be forwarded to the relevant app with some of these header values. Would I be able to achieve this with Lua?

That is how would I affect request headers within the ngx.location.capture directive?

Comment: Sure, all doable. Both the location.capture and the http client library I linked return a dictionary with the response headers that you can use for your purposes. 

E.g 
    `if res.header["X-Foo"] == "Foo value" then do_something() end`