# Intercept request and then forward to another Server

Tags: php, python, nginx, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

## Problem

I am facing a unique problem here. I have a nginx server with an admin panel (admin.example.com).  Now I want to allow only specific IP addresses to access that server and I know that we can do that through nginx allow and deny tag. But that approach is quite difficult for non-technical users and would require access to the server itself to make the change and then reload nginx. The purpose is to make it easy for anyone to whitelist IP addresses.

## Solution

We came up with a UI app.example.com (hosted on a different server)  to allow manage the IP addresses. Now I want to route all (admin.example.com) requests through this new server which will check if the IP is allowed then proxy the request to admin.example.com otherwise deny the access.

## Question

My question is how do we route all the requests through app.example.com and once the IP has been verified only then forward the request to the origin which is admin.example.com here?

If it is possible through the nginx reverse proxy then do I need to process the request through a local upstream such as PHP or python and then forward the request after the verification?

Anyone example with pseudo code for nginx configuration will be highly appreciated.

**I know services like Cloudflare does it but I need only a basic setup.**

Comment: As I understood, you want the users to whitelist IP addresses to allow access `admin.example.com`, well, I don't really understand why do you need an external server for it? Why don't you check the IP address inside your application? Or just use `iptables` to allow/deny IP addresses on port `80` / `443`.

Comment: Understood, but I want it for multiple applications on different servers.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that package requires changes to the nginx, my application has other components which I don't want to be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted [How do I make web service calls within nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778839/how-do-i-make-web-service-calls-within-nginx) . Another approach is to use the Openresty lua JIT to preprocess the request and then forward it to the reverse proxy.

https://openresty.org/en/